# iOS AdHoc App refuses to install on ONE device

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I have an internally developed app that I am distributing with AdHoc distribution. I have an intranet page setup with an *itms-services://?action=download-manifest* link to install it on the devices.

The app is currently deployed to 20 iOS 6 & 7 devices. **I tried to add 3 new iPod touches running iOS 8.**

Here's what I did:

1. Added the UDID of the 3 devices list on the developer.apple.com site
2. Added the three devices to the existing distribution profile (which is valid for another 8 months)
3. Generated a new archive for enterprise/adhoc distribution with the xCode organizer (generates a new ipa and plist)
4. Tried to install the app on the new devices using the itms-services link

**Problem**

Two of the three installed successfully. The third one absolutely refuses to install. When I tap the link to install, the Icon appears on the springboard and it just says "Waiting..." underneath it. Nothing ever happens. If I reboot the device, this message pops up: "Unable to download app. "SAP-WM" could not be downloaded at this time."

I verified that the UDID is correct and that it is associated with the distribution profile (it is). I also tried factory resetting the device and starting over to no avail. I also successfully deleted and re-installed the app on one of the other iOS 8 devices to ensure that the archive was OK, and it worked fine.

Here's the output from the console of the device from immediately after I tried the install (notice the errors about the zip being invalid? makes no sense, it works fine on the other two devices!):

```
Nov 24 07:53:03 iPod-touch locationd[62] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Nov 24 07:53:17 iPod-touch SpringBoard[42] <Warning>: Killing paulwieland.SAP-WM for app installation
Nov 24 07:53:17 iPod-touch itunesstored[79] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder <LSApplicationProxy: 0x146b5850> paulwieland.SAP-WM (Placeholder)
Nov 24 07:53:17 iPod-touch itunesstored[79] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x146b5850> paulwieland.SAP-WM (Placeholder) withPhase:1
Nov 24 07:53:18 iPod-touch lsd[72] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: 0x17560c60> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   to 1
Nov 24 07:53:18 iPod-touch installd[34] <Notice>: 0x505000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-5385180128768125426/5064573708106418894" type Customer requested by itunesstored (pid 79)
Nov 24 07:53:18 iPod-touch installd[34] <Error>: 0x505000 _IsValidZipArchiveAccordingToBom: File starts with 0x3c3f786d; expected 0x504b0304
Nov 24 07:53:18 iPod-touch installd[34] <Error>: 0x505000 -[MIInstaller _setupPackageStateWithError:]: Archive at /var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-5385180128768125426/5064573708106418894 doesn't appear to be a zip archive
Nov 24 07:53:18 iPod-touch installd[34] <Error>: 0x505000 bom_fatal_error_handler: BOMCopier signaled fatal error: Couldn't read PKZip signature
Nov 24 07:53:18 iPod-touch installd[34] <Error>: 0x505000 +[MIBOMWrapper extractZipArchiveAtURL:toURL:withError:]: 145: Could not extract archive (Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Undefined error: 0")
Nov 24 07:53:18 iPod-touch installd[34] <Error>: 0x505000 -[MIInstaller _extractPackageWithError:]: Failed to extract archive: Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=5 "Could not extract archive" UserInfo=0x17658b80 {LegacyErrorString=PackageExtractionFailed, FunctionName=+[MIBOMWrapper extractZipArchiveAtURL:toURL:withError:], NSLocalizedDescription=Could not extract archive, SourceFileLine=145, NSUnderlyingError=0x17557c70 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Undefined error: 0"}
Nov 24 07:53:18 iPod-touch itunesstored[79] <Error>: 0x2303000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke240: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=5 "Could not extract archive" UserInfo=0x145b56b0 {LegacyErrorString=PackageExtractionFailed, FunctionName=+[MIBOMWrapper extractZipArchiveAtURL:toURL:withError:], NSLocalizedDescription=Could not extract archive, SourceFileLine=145, NSUnderlyingError=0x145d9bc0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Undefined error: 0"}
Nov 24 07:53:18 iPod-touch itunesstored[79] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
Nov 24 07:53:18 iPod-touch lsd[72] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app paulwieland.SAP-WM
Nov 24 07:53:18 iPod-touch itunesstored[79] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: paulwieland.SAP-WM.Installing - <NSProgress: 0x145b6cb0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
Nov 24 07:53:21 iPod-touch locationd[62] <Warning>: PLClientLogging: log locationd withContent {
    } cannot continue due to nils!
Nov 24 07:53:21 iPod-touch locationd[62] <Warning>: PLClientLogging: log locationd withContent {
    } cannot continue due to nils!
Nov 24 07:53:22 iPod-touch locationd[62] <Warning>: notify name "com.apple.locationd.DumpDiagnostics" has been registered 20 times - this may be a leak
```

I'm really stumped!

Comment: Did you download the provisioning profile and rebuild the binary?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I ran into this when trying to update an app through an mdm. I ended up having to delete the app from the ipad, generate a new provisioning profile and then reinstall it onto the ipad. I still have no idea what was wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately I gave up. I ran out of time so I cheated and set the 3 devices as development devices and pushed the app to them via USB. That's not much help, I know...